# Claims when using "openid" scope in OIDc

Tags: openid-connect

In openidConnect if we use "openid" as the scope to invoke userinfo endpoint what are the expected claims to return? Can "email", "email_verifed" claims to be returned when we use the single scope "openid"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `openid` scope is merely a technical indicator that the client understands the OIDC "extension" to OAuth 2.0 and the server can e.g. safely add an ID Token to the token response.

What claims the ID Token, or the UserInfo response, will contain depends on the *identity* scopes that you request from the server. OIDC [defines four](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims): `profile`, `email`, `address`, `phone`, but servers may support others too.

If you *only* request the `openid` scope, then the expected claims returned by the server are most likely minimal, maybe even just an anonymous identifier, and will not include `email` and `email_verified`. For this you would add the `email` scope.